# Fake process after Ubuntu install

Tags: linux, process

after Ubuntu installation, I have a fake process after I run this command:

```
ps auxww | grep \\[ | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo PID: %; sha1sum /proc/%/exe' 2> /dev/null
```

From this article
https://blog.apnic.net/2020/04/27/detecting-linux-kernel-process-masquerading-with-command-line-forensics/

The hash I get is: `42e94914c7800c7063c51d7a17aec3a2069a3769  /proc/2531/exe`

After searching this Hash on Virustotal, I get this result:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/4f291296e89b784cd35479fca606f228126e3641f5bcaee68dee36583d7c9483/detection

It says that this file is distributed by Linux and Canonical.
But under "Behaviour" it has Mitre ATT&CK Tactics and Techniques detected.
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/4f291296e89b784cd35479fca606f228126e3641f5bcaee68dee36583d7c9483/behavior

Can someone help me? Is this a masqueraded linux process or a normal one?

Comment: Why do you call it "fake"?

Comment: Masquraded would be better

Comment: Why do you think that it is masqueraded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the process you mentioned and its associated hash may raise some concerns, it is important to approach such situations with caution and consider multiple aspects.

In this case, the process with the given PID and associated hash appears to belong to the Canonical package manager process "apt" in Ubuntu. Canonical is the company behind Ubuntu, and the hash result indicates that the file is distributed by Linux and Canonical. These are positive indicators that the process is legitimate.

Regarding the Mitre ATT&CK Tactics and Techniques detected in the VirusTotal report, it is not uncommon for legitimate processes to exhibit behaviors that could be associated with specific techniques. It doesn't necessarily mean that the process is malicious or masquerading.

However, i would take the following steps:

Confirm that the file path (/proc/2531/exe) corresponds to the expected location of the legitimate "apt" process on Ubuntu. Compare the hash value you obtained with the known hash values of the original "apt" executable, which can be obtained from reliable sources.

Run reputable antivirus or malware scanners on your system to scan the file and check for any potential threats. Utilize system monitoring and integrity checking tools, such as Tripwire or AIDE, to monitor and verify the integrity of critical system files.

Comment: Thank you, it seems it is an Ubuntu bug.

Comment: @Dion this doesn't seem like an Ubuntu bug. Perhaps a "bug" (or inherent naivety) in the one-liner command from the article. It assumes any command containing a square bracket is trying to trick you with the name, which is quite a jump.

Answer (score 2):

The one-liner command from the article looks for any process on your system that has an opening square bracket (`[`) in the process name or arguments. This is a rather naive check, as a process could contain nearly any character for any reason. For example, you may often see SSHD processes that contain `[priv]`, which should also be "detected" by that command.

Could a malicious process try to masquerade as a kernel thread by naming itself a certain way? Sure, but Occam's Razor applies. A malicious process could also do far more sinister things to completely hide itself.